# ABAP report toolbar is disabled

Tags: abap, alv, dynpro

I'm having trouble making the Toolbar(see image) of my SAP Report working despite having tried multiple solutions.

[image: Current Toolbar]

My report's code:

```
CLASS cl_orders_alv DEFINITION.
    PUBLIC SECTION.
      METHODS:
        on_init, on_display.

    PRIVATE SECTION.
      METHODS:
        on_data_fetch.

      DATA: ct_orders           TYPE TABLE OF zordhead_str,           " header itab
            ct_orders_pos       TYPE TABLE OF zordpos_str,            " pos itab

            co_orders_alvgrid   TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid,          " ALV Table
            co_ordpos_alvgrid   TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid,          " ALV Table

            co_orders_alvccntr  TYPE REF TO cl_gui_custom_container,  " Orders Head
            co_ordpos_alvccntr  TYPE REF TO cl_gui_custom_container,  " Orders Position

            cs_orders           TYPE zordhead_str,                    " header structure
            cs_orders_pos       TYPE zordpos_str,

            cs_orders_fieldcat  TYPE slis_fieldcat_alv,               " ALV Structure
            ct_orders_fieldcat  TYPE lvc_t_fcat,                      " ALV Table
            cs_ordpos_fieldcat  TYPE slis_fieldcat_alv,
            ct_ordpos_fieldcat  TYPE lvc_t_fcat.

  ENDCLASS.                    "cl_orders_alv

  CLASS cl_orders_alv IMPLEMENTATION.
    METHOD on_init.

      CLEAR ct_orders.
      CLEAR ct_orders_pos.
      CLEAR cs_orders.
      CLEAR cs_orders_pos.

      CREATE OBJECT co_orders_alvccntr
        EXPORTING
          container_name = 'ALV_CCONTAINER0'.

      CREATE OBJECT co_ordpos_alvccntr
        EXPORTING
          container_name = 'ALV_CCONTAINER1'.

      CREATE OBJECT co_orders_alvgrid
        EXPORTING
          i_parent = co_orders_alvccntr.

      CREATE OBJECT co_ordpos_alvgrid
        EXPORTING
          i_parent = co_ordpos_alvccntr.

      on_data_fetch( ).
    ENDMETHOD.                    "on_init

    METHOD on_display.
      CALL METHOD co_orders_alvgrid->set_table_for_first_display
        EXPORTING
          i_structure_name = 'ZORDHEAD_STR'
        CHANGING
          it_outtab        = ct_orders.

      CALL METHOD co_ordpos_alvgrid->set_table_for_first_display
        EXPORTING
          i_structure_name = 'ZORDPOS_STR'
        CHANGING
          it_outtab        = ct_orders_pos.

      CALL SCREEN '0100'.
    ENDMETHOD.                    "on_display

    METHOD on_data_fetch.
      CALL FUNCTION 'LVC_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE'
        EXPORTING
          i_structure_name       = 'ZORDHEAD_STR'
        CHANGING
          ct_fieldcat            = ct_orders_fieldcat
        EXCEPTIONS
          inconsistent_interface = 1
          program_error          = 2
          OTHERS                 = 3.

      CALL FUNCTION 'LVC_FIELDCATALOG_MERGE'
        EXPORTING
          i_structure_name       = 'ZORDPOS_STR'
        CHANGING
          ct_fieldcat            = ct_ordpos_fieldcat
        EXCEPTIONS
          inconsistent_interface = 1
          program_error          = 2
          OTHERS                 = 3.

    ENDMETHOD.                    "on_data_fetch
  ENDCLASS.                    "CL_ORDERS_ALV IMPLEMENTATION

  START-OF-SELECTION.
    SET PF-STATUS 'STANDARD_FULLSCREEN'.

    DATA: go_alv_gui TYPE REF TO cl_orders_alv.

    CREATE OBJECT go_alv_gui.
    go_alv_gui->on_init( ).
    go_alv_gui->on_display( ).
```

This is what I have tried so far:

- Copied an existing Status into my Program/Report:

  - Go to Transaction `SE41`
  - `User Interface` => `Copy` => `Status...`
  - From: `Program`= `SAPLSLVC_FULLSCREEN` ; `Status`=`STANDARD_FULLSCREEN`
  - To: `Program` = `ZESXDV` ; `Status` = `STANDARD_FULLSCREEN`
  - Hit Ok.
  - Go to Transaction `SE80` and open up your Report/Program
  - The `GUI Status` folder is created, inside of which there's the new copied status.
- Added the following instruction in the report's code(after `START-OF-SELECTION`):

  - `SET PF-STATUS 'STANDARD_FULLSCREEN'.`

Note: I noticed that the Toolbar doesn't work only when working with ALV tables and custom ALV Containers(which both needs a Screen Object[which is called by the `CALL SCREEN 'XXXX'` instruction.])

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S.: *If some info are missing let me know and I'll add them as soon as possible.*

Comment: you should paste
“SET PF-STATUS 'STANDARD_FULLSCREEN'.” 
in pbo module on screen 0100. You enable screen code as below

PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
MODULE STATUS_0100.
*
PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
MODULE USER_COMMAND_0100. 

paste into MODULE STATUS_0100.

Comment: @MustafaHamit Doesn't work. I'm putting `MODULE STATUS_0100. SET PF-STATUS 'STANDARD_FULLSCREEN'. ENDMODULE.` right before `START-OF-SELECTION`.

Comment: No, as you can see in debug your PBO module is not triggered. The PBO modules are declared this way: `MODULE STATUS_0100 OUTPUT.`

Comment: you can check standart report tcode SE38 enter "BCALV_GRID_07" goto screen 0100 and goto MODULE pbo_100 OUTPUT. you will see SET PF-STATUS 'MAIN100' code. Must be active gui status and same way.

Comment: Thanks @MustafaHamit, now it works. I've posted an answer based on what you've said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use screen code as below

```
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
  MODULE PBO_100.
*
PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
  MODULE PAI_100.
```

creating perform module and put your into pf-status

```
MODULE pbo_100 OUTPUT.

  SET PF-STATUS 'MAIN100'.
  set titlebar 'MAIN100'.

ENDMODULE.                             " PBO_100  OUTPUT
```

Note: check activeted gui status "MAIN100"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Mustafa Hamit. I'll post what I've done baesd on @Mustafa Hamit's comment.

---

- Go to the Screen object(Double click on `CALL SCREEN 100`).
- Navigate to tab `Flow Logic`.
- Insert `MODULE PBO_100.` right after `PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.`.
- Insert `MODULE PAI_100.` right after `PROCESS AFTER INPUT.`.
- Double click on `PBO_100` -> `Create Object`
- On the `PBO_100` screen write `SET PF-STATUS '{NAME OF THE STATUS}'` between `MODULE pbo_100 OUTPUT.` and `ENDMODULE`.
- Go back and create the `PAI_100` object(double click on it).
- Activate everything.
- Two `INCLUDE` statements should appear on your report's code at the end of the program.
- The Toolbar should now be enabled and functional.

---